# Matplotlib in Spyder: plot shows immediately

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I'm trying to use the matplotlib.pyplot package in Spyder: everytime I plot something, as

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

the plot shows immediately, without the call to .show(). This is bothering me, since if I make an adjustment, like

```
plt.ylab('try this')
```

it shows a brand new plot with the label but without the data.
What am I missing?

Python 3.4.3
Spyder 3.0.0dev
Qt 5.5.1

Comment: One more thing: if I enter plt.show() it doesn't plot anything.

Comment: You can switch interactive modes with plt.ion() and plt.ioff(), but I don't think the problem is that it shows the plot immediately. When I try to reproduce your problem, the label in my existing plot changes (using plt.ylabel() (typo?)). Check your settings in Preferences - Console - External modules. The GUI backend for matplotlib is for me Qt4Agg.

Comment: You're right, the problem was in the settings. The backend was set to "inline", I changed it to "Qt" and now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all [pyplot functions](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) support the *hold* boolean. Have you tried that? It should stop from plotting immediatly.

> Additional kwargs: hold = [True|False] overrides default hold state

Comment: Both plt.plot([1,2,3,4], hold=True) and plt.plot([1,2,3,4], hold=False) return immediately the figure.

Comment: have you tried adding it as a subplot? most of the examples on the api page use that.

Comment: I've tried an example on that page, but it doesn't work. Every time I enter the subplot, Spyder shows it on the screen. At the end, when I enter plt.show(), nothing appears.